# Binding и EntityFramework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, binding

У меня в проекте есть partial классы объектов, созданных с помощью Entity framework. В них есть вычисляемые свойства, т.е. они имеют только геттер.

В проекте есть объект Sale(продажа) и связанный список Sales_composition(состав продажи). Необходимо отразить изменение итога продажи и суммы состава, при изменении количества.

Сам список состава привязан BindigList. Тут проблем нет. Проблема состоит только в правильном определении OnPropertyChanged, ведь сеттер вычисляемому свойству не нужен, а обновление происходит именно через этот блок.

Не могу понять, как это сделать с помощью OnPropertyChanged правильно. Слышала ещё про DependencyObject, но мне кажется, что этот тип реализуется где-то на стороне WPF.

---

1. Получилось привязать Сумму по строке, но свойство итога не обновляется, т.к. находится в другом объекте, но ссылку не находит.
2. С помощью ***костыля***, при котором свойство итога всё же имеет геттер, в котором прописан OnPropertyChanged() и вызова присваивания ему любого числа, всё же получилось реализовать подсчёт итога. Но я более чем уверена, что это не правильно.

*Хочется узнать, как это сделать без MVVM. С помощью него делать гораздо проще и правильнее, но больше интересно узнать, реально ли это с помощью такого подхода.*

В скриншоте для удобства объединила partial классы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При изменении списка вызывайте PropertyChanged с названием вычисляемого свойства.

Comment: Например, если у вас есть цена и количество, которые могут меняться и вычисляемое свойство для итоговой стоимости, то вам надо в сеттер цены и количества добавить также оповещение об изменении итога: `public decimal Price { get ... set { _price = value; OnPropertyChanged(); OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Total)); } }`

Comment: *находится в другом объекте* — у вас трудности из-за того, что вы используете один и тот же класс для нескольких целей (для EF и в качестве VM). Разделите классы по ответственности и вопрос решен: все необходимые свойства будут в одном классе

Comment: Да, можно и без mvvm, предыдущий комментарий в силе. Используйте несколько классов для разных целей, не "экономьте" классы, это вылезет проблемой и все равно придется переписывать на несколько классов, лучше сделать это сразу, тем более проблемы и костыли вы уже ощущаете

Comment: После того как вы отдадите класс для EF, в нем не останется ничего лишнего и никакого мусора (в том числе INPC ему не нужен, например). А класс для отображения на UI вообще можно будет сделать один вместо двух и тогда все свойства окажутся в одном классе. Либо, например, если у вас заказ и в нем коллекция позиций и вы хотите обновлять итоговую сумму на заказе, если изменилась одна из позиций, просто подпишитесь в заказе на событие PropertyChanged каждой позиции и вызывайте OnPropertyChanged там. Главное тут не забудьте отписаться в нужный момент, чтобы не было утечек